# How do I remove myclk.net script form Google Chrome in Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus)?

Tags: google-chrome, malware

I am facing a malware problem on my [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus).
The problem is Google Chrome always try to connect to this site:

http://myclk.net

It uses the script

**HTTPROTOCOL://myclk.net/js/tx.js**

and sends all data inside any form opened in Chrome to it

```
http://myclk.net/replacement/ping?place=3265&subid=51020 3010
```

(The above URLs are shown in Chrome's Firebug lite extension. Chrome's default console (via inspect element) shows nothing.)

Till now I've tried:

1. Updated Chrome (problem not solved)
2. Cleared everything including cache and history (problem not solved)
3. Checked Chrome extensions, no suspicious extension installed (problem not solved)
4. Checked installed search engines in Chrome, but no suspicious search engine was present (problem not solved)
5. Checked install applications via software centers (no malicious application installed) (problem not solved)

Could you please suggest me any malware cleaner for Ubuntu as I couldn't find any suitable one or suggest me any other place inside OS to find it out?

Here is the screenshot of the Firebug console:

[Firebug Extension Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18L4k.png)

Comment: Did you check google search with the search keys "chrome myclk.net remove" ? I found(as one example)  "Remove myclk.net From Your Browser" --> http://www.sitealyzer.net/en/p/sb/remove-myclk.net/

Comment: ...and please keep in mind: this is a more general problem and not specific to Ubuntu.

Comment: You could try to delete _all_ chrome data :  delete the folder `~/.config/google-chrome` and `~/.cache/google-chrome` (You need to press Ctrl + H in the file manager to see this folder, as it's a hidden folder). Note that this will delete all chrome data, including history, saved passwords, and so on.

Comment: @JonasCz thanks, I did so, but it didn't removed my saved passwords and browsing history and also the problem is not solved.

Comment: Did you quit chrome before deleting this folder ? Make sure that chrome is closed and run this in a therminal:  `rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/ && rm -rf ~/.cache/google-chrome`, which should clear all chrome data.

Comment: @JonasCz  yes I forgot to close Chrome, now it worked thanks buddy, you saved my whole day.

Comment: @JonasCz problem solved, you can add your suggestions as answer to this question. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution for this kind of problem is to delete *all* browser data, (including cache, cookies, and so on), which will also delete any malicious scripts / extensions which may be installed.

For Chrome, you can do this by closing Chrome and then running

```
rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/ && rm -rf ~/.cache/google-chrome
```

in a terminal, which will delete all Chrome data, including any malicious extensions. Beware that this will delete *all* data, including history, saved passwords, and so on.

If this does not solve the problem, you may have other malware (for example, software which you didn't install through the software center and which did not come from the Ubuntu repositories could be malicious) on your computer which is reinstalling the malicious Chrome extension - you'll need to find and remove it first.